# How do I simulate a vector field from the Boit-Savart law for a coil?

Tags: java, math, simulation, physics

I am trying to create a program that simulates a magnetic field distribution around the end of a coil in java. To do this I have decided to use the Boit-Savart law around a circular loop though I'm struggling to get it to work as I still haven't learnt this stuff yet (I am in high school). The goal is to capture the field distribution in this orientation from the coil:
[field distribution from coil, rectangle is what needs to be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Naajb.png)

To do this I have decided to create a Point class that stores a point's (x,y) location and strength vectors bx, by at that point. Then the program creates an ArrayList for every point P(x,y) within the screen's dimensions and calculates the x and y vectors at every point. I currently have this:

```
public class Point {
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double b;
    public double bx;
    public double by;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.b = 0;
        this.bx = 0;
        this.by = 0;
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Simulation {
    ArrayList<Point> points;
    static double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    static double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;


    public Simulation() {
        this.points = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void pointArray() {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 800; x++) { // 800 width
            for (int y = 0; y <= 800; y++) { // 800 height
                Point p = new Point(x, y);
                calculateVectors(p);

                // update min/max
                if (p.b > max) {
                    max = p.b;
                } else if (p.b < min) {
                    min = p.b;
                }

                points.add(p);
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Point> getPoints() {
        pointArray();
        return points;
    }

    public static void calculateVectors(Point p) {
        double loopRadius = 100; // Radius of the loop in physical z-direction
        double current = 50; // Current through the loop
        double mu0 = 4 * Math.PI * 1E-7; // Permeability of free space
        double dTheta = 2 * Math.PI / 100; // Discretization step in radians
        double Bz = 0.0; // Bx from calculation, but physically Bz
        double By = 0.0; // Stays as By in both calculation and physical space

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            double theta = i * dTheta;
            // Loop coordinates in the calculation xy-plane (interpreted as xz in physical space)
            double segmentX = loopRadius * Math.cos(theta); // Physically z-coordinate
            double segmentY = loopRadius * Math.sin(theta); // Stays as y-coordinate

            // Displacement vector from this segment to the observation point
            double rx = (p.x - segmentX) * 0.01; // p.z is used for physical z, mapped from calculated x
            double ry = (p.y - segmentY) * 0.01; // y-coordinate remains unchanged
            double r = Math.sqrt(rx * rx + ry * ry);

            if (r > 1E-6) { // Avoid division by zero
                // dl vector tangent to the loop, in the calculation plane
                double dlx = -Math.sin(theta) * loopRadius * dTheta; // Physically dlz
                double dly = Math.cos(theta) * loopRadius * dTheta; // Stays as dly

                // Magnetic field contribution from this segment
                double dBz = (mu0 * current / (4 * Math.PI)) * (dly * rx - dlx * ry) / (r * r * r); // Calculated as dBx, interpreted as dBz
                Bz += dBz * (rx / r); // Physically Bz contribution
                By += dBz * (ry / r); // By contribution
            }
        }

        // Assign the calculated field components to the Point object
        p.bx = Bz; // Calculated Bx interpreted as Bz
        p.by = By;
        // Calculate the magnitude of the B field vector in the zy-plane
        p.b = Math.sqrt(Bz * Bz + By * By);
    }
}
```

The issue with what chatgpt gave me is that the coil is oriented towards the screen when it should be pointing sideways (like in the drawing above). How can I fix this?

Comment: My advice is to write the code yourself, without ChatGPT; otherwise what you learn is how to use ChatGPT, not anything about physics or programming. I would back up and have another go at it. The simplest way to solve physics problems like this is to work with a array representing a grid on the (x, y) plane. Octave (a Matlab clone) is a convenient environment for working with arrays -- you will find it much simpler than an equivalent program in Java. Try a very small grid first, say 10 by 10. Try to work with operations on whole arrays instead of looping over indices. Good luck and have fun.